# customXmlParts() null asyncResult.id

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I have the following code as part of the javascript for a Word add-in:

```html
function createCustomXmlPartAndStoreID() {
  const xmlString = "<Reviewers xmlns='http://schemas.contoso.com/review/1.0'><Reviewer>Mark</Reviewer><Reviewer>Hong</Reviewer><Reviewer>Sally</Reviewer></Reviewers>";
  Office.context.document.customXmlParts.addAsync(xmlString,
      (asyncResult) => {
          Office.context.document.settings.set('ReviewersID', asyncResult.id);
          console.log('SET: ' + asyncResult.id);
          Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                console.log('Settings save failed. Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Settings saved.');
            }
          });
      }
  );
  getReviewers();
}
function getReviewers() {
  const reviewersXmlId = Office.context.document.settings.get('ReviewersID');
  console.log('GOT: ' + reviewersXmlId);
  Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByIdAsync(reviewersXmlId,
      (asyncResult) => {
          asyncResult.value.getXmlAsync(
              (asyncResult) => {
                  $("#xml-blob").text(asyncResult.value);
              }
          );
      }
  );
```

It's cobbled together from [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings?view=office-js#how-to-save-custom-xml-to-the-document)

Running the add-in in Word, in the console I get the following messages:
GOT: null
Error: Function getByIdAsync has invalid parameters.
SET: undefined
Settings saved.

So, the XML settings are saved (and I can see them in the document) – itemXX.xml has:

```html
<Reviewers xmlns="http://schemas.contoso.com/review/1.0"><Reviewer>Mark</Reviewer><Reviewer>Hong</Reviewer><Reviewer>Sally</Reviewer></Reviewers>
```

However, what I expect to be a valid ReviewersID is actually undefined, when it is set, then null when I try to retrieve it with the result that getByIdAsync() throws an error.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

EDIT: I'm edging closer to a solution but still some problems:

```html
function addXMLPartandHandler() {
  Office.context.document.customXmlParts.addAsync(
      "<testns:book xmlns:testns='http://testns.com'><testns:page number='1'>Hello</testns:page><testns:page number='2'>world!</testns:page></testns:book>",
      function(r) {
          console.log('1 addAsyncID: ' + r.value.id); 
          Office.context.document.settings.set('WikindxID', r.value.id);
          r.value.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DataNodeDeleted,
          function(a) {
            console.log(a.type); 
            console.log(a);
          },
              function(s) {
                console.log('2 ' + s.status);
              });
      });
      Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
      var wikindxXmlID = Office.context.document.settings.get('WikindxID');
      console.log('3 WikindxID: ' + wikindxXmlID);
      Office.context.document.bindings.getByIdAsync(wikindxXmlID, function (asyncResult) {
        console.log('4 ' + asyncResult.status);
      });
}
```

In the console, this produces:

```
3 WikindxID: {4A32BF0A-A11D-7141-82DD-F4441E467099}
1 addAsyncID: {7F685839-E425-B145-9C32-ED0F3C58CD49}
4 failed
2 succeeded
```

I want WikindxID to be the value from addSyncID but it always lags one behind and this is the reason why I get the failure message. The issue is the order of execution and here my knowledge of the javascript logic falls down – I don't know why I don't get the messages in the order 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: See what happens if you put the `async` keyword before each of the asynchronous methods, like addAsync and addHandlerAsync, etc.

Comment: I guess async would do the trick but my code has moved on and I've found another way to do what I want using content containers. Thanks for the response anyway.